# Let $(a_n)\subset\mathbb{C}$ be bounded. Then $T_a\colon\ell^p\to\ell^p, \ (T_a x)_n:=a_n x_n$ compact iff $a_n\to0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, compact-operators

(See title.) I think that I know how to prove $\implies$: If $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $\ell^p$, then there is a $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\|x_n\|\leq c$ for all $n$. So $$\|T_a x_n\|=\|a_n x_n\|\leq c\|a_n\|\to0,$$ from which it follows that any subsequence of $(T_a x_n)$ in $\ell^p$ converges (to $0$). (Is this correct?) However, for the converse, I have no idea. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764477/problem-about-a-compact-operator-tlp-rightarrow-lp).

Comment: I don't see why the identity $\lVert (a_kx_{n,k}\,:\, k\in\Bbb N)\rVert=\lVert a_nx_n\rVert$ should hold.

Comment: Perhaps I have overlooked something, but it seems the proposed target duplicate has only one answer, consisting of a "hint" for the direction of implication that OP here says "that I know how to prove".  So while both Questions pose an "iff" claim, the direction $\impliedby$ remains open.